# Where I can download F# 3.0

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Where can I obtain a copy of the F# 3.0 compiler and tools? (Similar to F# 2.0 CTP release http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18706). I am not looking for F# as part of Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: -1 for no effort. Google gives several good links to the developer preview. There is no mention of an RTM. That is, it is _not_ ready.

Comment: @Oded Please read my question again.. `I have mentioned not as a part of VS 11 developer preview.. :-)`

Comment: F# 3.0 has not gone RTM, so how would it be available?

Comment: I think I know where the confusion comes from. F# is not available as part of the VS dev11 developer preview that is pre-installed on windows 8. It is available as part of the VS dev11 developer preview that is downloaded and installed separately from Windows 8. Download that here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543

Comment: Can someone please reopen this question so I can answer it?

Comment: Until the question gets reopened, I'll answer it here in the comments. Answer

Comment: Until the question gets reopened, I'll answer it here in the comments. Answer: Microsoft has not officially anounced any plans to release F# 3.0 outside of Visual Studio 2012.  According to some public posts, there are expectations that an MSI or SDK will be released similar to the F# 2.0 compiler and tools release (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fsharpgeneral/thread/3c80298a-d12b-45db-b0d7-8d6e9c8486f9). But as of today August 30th, 2012, the only F# 3.0 compiler currently available is the one that comes with Visual Studio 2012 Professional or above.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed. There is still no download from MS but you can build the compiler from source from the github repo. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

Comment: How is this "not a real question"?    What Mr. Exception is asking seems rather obvious to me...